# Is there any easier way than split function?

Tags: c#

Well, I know this can be very basic functionality of C#. 
But I didn't used since years so Asking this....

I have a string like MyName-1_1#1233

I want to pick only the numbers/characters from between of  - , _ and # ...

I can use split function, but it take quite big code...is there anything else ?

for picking the numbers from the string, I supposed to write like below code

```
string[] words = s.Split('-');
    foreach (string word in words)
    {
       //getting two separate string and have to pick the number using index... 
    }

  string[] words = s.Split('_');
    foreach (string word in words)
    {
       //getting two separate string and have to pick the number using index... 
    }

     string[] words = s.Split('#');
    foreach (string word in words)
    {
       //getting two separate string and have to pick the number using index... 
    }
```

Comment: what is the output you want

Comment: The split function isn't that big. Why not show us what you mean by posting the code in your question?

Comment: Sounds like a job for Regular Expressions

Comment: you can use more than one delimiter with Split

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expressions for this:

```
        string S = "-1-2#123#3";
        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(S, "(?<=[_#-])(\\d+)(?=[_#-])?"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1]);
        }
```

Comment: want to get only number between two symbols

Comment: You want 1, 2, 123 in above example and not 3 ?

Comment: ya, I want 3 as well ...it dont give 3

Comment: what change I have to made , if I have string like Invoice-1_2#5!7878

Comment: Change [_#-] to [_#!-].

Answer (score 0):

A bit shorter:

```
    List<char> badChars = new List<char>{'-','_','#'};
    string str = "MyName-1_1#1233";
    string output = new string(str.Where(ch => !badChars.Contains(ch)).ToArray());
```

output will be `MyName111233`

If you want only the numbers then:

```
    string str = "MyName-1_1#1233";
    string output = new string(str.Where(ch => char.IsDigit(ch)).ToArray());
```

output will be `111233`